# Поднять элементы UIView вверх при появлении клавиатуры swift

Tags: ios, swift, клавиатура

Всем привет. Я хочу поднять вверх элементы `uiview` при появлении клавиатуры. Мой код заключается в следующем:
1. Создал слушателей:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

2. Удаляю слушатель:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

3. И описываю три метода:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            kbHeight = keyboardSize.height
            self.animatedTextField(true)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.animatedTextField(false)
}

func animatedTextField(up: Bool) {
   let movement = (up ? -kbHeight : kbHeight)

   UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement)
   })
}
```

Я хочу написать комментарии на пост, нажимаю на `uitextfield` и появляется клава. Пишу и отправляю в базу. Но после того как я отправляю комментарии в базу, элементы `uiview` поднимаются еще два раза (при отправлении идет прогресс худ). Как это исправить?

Comment: поставьте брейкпоинты, посмотрите что где не так

Comment: почему бы не библиотека? Например: IQKeyboardManager